# Model new with params, initialize all attributes with nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I init a ItemMedida object with some attributes values

```
item_medida = SpfPedido::ItemMedida.new(cantidad: 3, ancho: 800, alto: 600)
```

But when I call it, all attributes are nil

```
item_medida #=> <SpfPedido::ItemMedida id: nil, cantidad: nil, ancho: nil, alto: nil)
```

cantidad, alto, ancho are defined ok in DB.

Why I get this behaviour? I want my object intialized with their correct attributes.
Any tip?

The model

```
# encoding: utf-8
module SpfPedido
  class ItemMedida < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :item, class_name: "SpfPedido::Item", inverse_of: :item_medidas
    belongs_to :medida
    has_many :pulidos, class_name: "SpfPedido::Pulido"
    has_many :agujeros, class_name: "SpfPedido::Agujero"
    has_many :entrantes, class_name: "SpfPedido::Entrante"
    has_many :solapes, class_name: "SpfPedido::Solape"
    has_one :forma
    has_and_belongs_to_many :adjuntos
    has_many :adjunto_medidas
    has_many :adjuntos, through: :adjunto_medidas
    has_many :curvaturas
    has_many :bites
    has_many :tango_bodies, as: :linea_item, class_name: 'SpfTango::TangoBody'
    # Polymorphic
    has_one :pre_facturacion, as: :linea_item
    has_one :facturacion, as: :linea_item
    has_one :expedicion, as: :linea_item
    has_many :trazabilidads, through: :item
    #############
    has_and_belongs_to_many :orden_corte_mesas # creo que no va mas
    has_many :medidas_orden_corte_mesas
    has_many :comprobante_medidas
    has_many :comprobante_temps, through: :comprobante_medidas
    has_many :rotura_vidrios
    has_many :elementos, through: :item
    has_many :proceso_de_elementos, through: :item
    has_many :componentes, through: :item
    has_many :proceso_de_componentes, through: :item
    delegate :pedido, to: :item
    before_update :cambio_de_medidas?, :if => proc { ancho_changed? || alto_changed? } 
    validates :cantidad, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0, less_than: 1000, message: "Debe introducirse un valor entero entre 0 y 999" } 
    validates :ancho, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0, less_than: 10000, message: "Debe introducirse un valor entero entre 0 y 9999" }
    validates :alto, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0, less_than: 10000, message: "Debe introducirse un valor entero entre 0 y 9999"  }
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :medida
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :solapes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :pulidos
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bites
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :curvaturas
    attr_accessor :config_pulido_id
    attr_accessor :objeto_pulible_type
    attr_accessor :objeto_pulible_id
    attr_accessor :accion
    attr_accessor :cambio_de_medidas
    attr_accessor :comentario
    attr_accessor :total_de_complementos # es la suma de complementos del item
    attr_accessor :precio_unitario_con_complementos # total_linea + total_complementos / superficie
  end
end
```

I want item_medida to be `<SpfPedido::ItemMedida id: nil, cantidad: 3, ancho: 600, alto: 800>`

EDIT:

Another test.

```
item_medida = SpfPedido::ItemMedida.new(cantidad: 3, ancho: 800, alto: 600)
item_medida #=> <SpfPedido::ItemMedida id: nil, cantidad: nil, ancho: nil, alto: nil>
item_medida.valid? #=> false
item_medida = SpfPedido::ItemMedida.new(cantidad: 3, ancho: 800, alto: 600)
item_medida #=> <SpfPedido::ItemMedida id: nil, cantidad: 3, ancho: 800, alto: 600>
```

After calling `.valid?` method, the item_medida object is initialized correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what  is the `Object`, is this `AR` object? Where is it defined?

Comment: I'm not sure what to you want to achieve. You want save that values in a `Object`? or in a `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: ItemMedida inherits from ActiveRecord.

Comment: I have edited the title and the question content

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: What happens if you do `create!` instead of `new`?

Comment: In the terminal, make sure your current directory is for the current project and enter `rails console`. Then enter `SpfPedido::ItemMedida.table_name` and tell us what string appears

Comment: SpfPedido::ItemMedida.table_name returns 'item_medidas', which is ok

Comment: If i do create! instead of new, i get a RecordInvalid exception, cause attributes are nil and I have presence validations on cantidad, ancho and alto attributes. Im uploading the complete model now

Comment: Are you using some `attr_accessor` stuff? If so, remove it.

Comment: I use attr_accesor but not on :cantidad, :ancho and :alto attributes. Should I remove attr_accessors anyway?

Comment: No, not if it doesn't affect those attributes. Have you tried commenting everything out and trying that? Then comment things in one by one.

Comment: Just remember to reload! the console, have forgotten that myself a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I found the anomaly. It was my mistake. My model includes a module where there was a wrong method_missing redefinition, without using super, like this:

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  if condition
    #do something
  end
end
```

So I have corrected it with

```
def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
  if condition
    #do something
  else
    super(m, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!